# Convert given two complex number division into polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

Sorry if I am breaking any rule. But I really need help with polar form because I have an exam Tomorrow.

> Suppose $z=1+i$ and $w=1−i\sqrt3$. Write $q=z^6/w^5$ in polar form and calculate its modulus.

What I have tried so far:
First, I found z

z=$√2(\cos \Pi/4+ i sin \Pi/4)$

then W

r = $√(1+3) = 2$
z=$√2(\cos\theta + i sin\theta)$

but I  don't know how to find theta here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You, don't just ask with urgency. _Provide context_ with urgency!

Comment: Please edit the question to show us how you have started. Then perphaps we can help. Can you write $1+i$ in polar form?

Comment: What is $\theta$ in your formula for $z$? Then do $w$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: what is it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625017/convert-given-two-complex-number-division-into-polar-form/2631248#2631248?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked : 
$z=1+iz=1+i$

$w=1−i3$

$q=z^6/w^5$

1.) Calculate the exponential form of q

2.) Calculate the modulus

---

1.)

$z = √2(cos(\pi/4)+ isin(\pi/4), z= \sqrt2e\^(i\pi/4)$
$w = √2(cos(-\pi/3)+ isin(-\pi/3), w= \sqrt2e\^(-i\pi/4)$

$z^6 = 8e\^(i3/2\pi)$

$w^5=32e\^(-i5/3\pi9$

$q= 1/4e\^(i19/6\pi)$

---

2.)
$|q|= 1/4$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Write z and w in exponential form then compute $z^6$ and $w^5$ then divide.

Comment: I did polar form for z but stuck on w, don't know how to find theta

Comment: Draw it and it will be extremely obvious.

Comment: Sorry I mean exponential, for w $\theta=-\pi/3$

Comment: could you calculate w only?

Comment: w has modulus 2 thus $$w =2\cdot e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}$$